# Chart JS - Is there a way to connect two datasets in a line chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to connect two data in a dataset of  Chart but I can't figure out how to do so, currently my chart looks like this:
[image: Line Chart]

I wanted to connect it like this:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
                  <Line
                       type={'line'}
                       data={{
                       labels: [dtOne, dtTwo, dtThree, dtFour, dtFive,
                                dtSix, dtSeven, 'Today',  dtEight, dtNine, 
                                dtTen, dtEleven, dtTwelve, dtThirteen, dtFourteen],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                            label: 'Cash Net +',
                            data: 
                                [
                                22230000, 31150000, 28300000, 2640000, 27510000,
                                -9011000, 26810000, 13970000
                                ],
                            borderColor: 
                                [
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(255, 82, 82, 1)',
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)'
                                ],
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 0)',
                            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                            pointStyle: 'circle',
                            pointRadius: 5,
                            lineTension: 0
                        },
                            {
                            label: 'Forecast +',
                            data: 
                                [
                                null, null, null, null, null,
                                null, null, null, -12820000, 22900000,
                                25710000, 9330000, -31040000, 27999000, -11190000
                                ],
                            borderColor: 
                                [
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 82, 82, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 82, 82, 1)', 'rgba(46, 111, 255, 1)',
                                'rgba(255, 82, 82, 1)'
                                ],
                            borderDash: [40],
                            borderDashOffset: 100,
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 82, 82, 0)',
                            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)',
                            pointStyle: 'rect',
                            pointRadius: 5,
                            borderDash: [12],
                            lineTension: 0
                        }
                       }}
                  />
```

I tried to put the same value on the last null of the second dataset (from the first dataset), I was able to connect the lines but the problem is whenever I click that specific point I get 2 values (which is understandable)

[image]

I'm just looking for alternatives if I could perhaps connect these 2 datasets without doing that.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for almost a week now.. and any help is appreciated.

Comment: i think specifying start for your second data set can help. I thinks something like this can help you https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056

Comment: Hi Rutu - Can you please elaborate on what part of my code should I change? Because I'm quite new on this and don't know how to use github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the line yourself on the canvas with a custom plugin: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html

You can also use the anotation plugin to draw the line for you: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation

Comment: Hi - can you please specify on how or what I need to add in my code because I am quite new to this. Thanks!